# Decimal Point causing values in CSV values to add incorrectly

Tags: c#, web-services, csv

I have the following values in CSV form -

fact, tact

10.5, 11.5

15.5, 16.5

I am sending these to a web service and they are getting stored in a database. The response from the web service should equal the sum of the values in thier respective column -

i.e. for 'fact' the response back should equal 10.5 + 15.5 therefore = 26,
and for 'tact' 11.5 + 16.5 therefore = 28.

however the deciaml point seems to be causing issues with the results response and ignoring the digits after it getting 'fact' = 25 and 'tact' = 27.

I am using the following code to find the appropriate value in the csv and set it to a position in an object array -

```
upDateFeed[i] = new webservice.upDateFeed();

upDateFeed[i].fact = (int)System.Convert.ToDouble(el.Descendants("var").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") =="fact").SingleOrDefault().Attribute("value").Value);
upDateFeed[i].tact = (int)System.Convert.ToDouble(el.Descendants("var").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") =="tact").SingleOrDefault().Attribute("value").Value);
```

How can I get it to take the digits after the deciaml points into consideration?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: what is `el`?   What is `webservice.upDateFeed()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're explicitly converting the `double` to `int`, what do you expect would happen? :)

Comment: I agree.  you have to unbox to (double) not (int).

Comment: @Lane - No unboxing would be required as the OP is using the `Convert.ToDouble` function.

Comment: @Lane, `ToDouble` already returns `double` so there's no need for an explicit conversion.

Comment: @IIya - that would then result in a compiler error as the webservice expects an integer. The webservice has to be updated (also the backend DB) to accept floating-point values for this work.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting your double to an int which means it will remove any floating point precision. You need to update your `upDateFeed` class expect a `double` instead of an `int` and then you don't need to do any casting.

Also just from a readability point of view you should break up your code a little so it is a bit clearer to see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: I have no control over what the upDateFeed class can expect, it has been configured by the author of the web service I am consuming.

Comment: @Lambo - Can you confirm that properties `fact`/`tact` are definitely integers?

Comment: yes absolutely, the table that stores these numbers stores them as integers.

Comment: @Lambo - I am afraid that is your problem then. If the database only stores integers (and you have no control over this) then I am afraid the only data it can accept are integers. To store floating-point values you would not only need to update the webservice but also the database field type.

Answer (score 0):

if the web service will only accept int's you will not be able to get the figures you want. It will always be rounded

upDateFeed[i].fact

upDateFeed[i].tact

both need to be of a type which has decimal spaces, the cast you are doing to int means the decimals are being removed. I assume because the webservice only accepts ints and not decimals. If that's the case the web service needs to change.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Kev, just to ask, I did try a few things and it always took me back to what you said - I believe the web service is confugured to accept both fact and tact as integers therefore it is impossible for me to send it anything else?

Comment: yes that's what I would expect, if you cant change the web service you are stuck